# In Interstellar, how did humans survive the first time in order to communicate?

Tags: interstellar

Throughout Interstellar, there are many references to "They" - the advanced species that created a multidimensional spacetime artifact that allowed Cooper to talk with Murphy. The movie makes it pretty clear that "They" are an advanced humanity.

They create the wormhole that enables the whole plot of Interstellar.

My question:

- How did these humans survive in order to do this, in the first place?

Humankind only survives because of the effects of the wormhole, both allowing travel to other worlds and a new colony and Cooper communicating backwards in time. I don't understand how either of these would have happened however given that both are precipitated on humankind *already* surviving and causing them.

Comment: @Valorum the question you linked is not about how humans survive to that point, but rather takes it for granted that they did and asks why they did not do certain things at that point. I am asking about how they were able to survive to _allow_ that linked question to even happen.

Comment: Doesn't make your premise any less flawed. There *never* was a reality where humans survived without the wormhole, it's a self-consistent closed temporal loop.

Comment: Related: [How could the human race be saved in Interstellar?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27218/49)

Comment: @enderland - Because they went back in time. One of the joys of a closed time loop is that there doesn't need to be a first mover. That's why it's called a "paradox".

Comment: “First” loses meaning once time travel is involved.